# Which part of speech the word "all" belongs to? (in this context ), What's the use of this(all) in this context?

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech

Then it made **all** the sense in the world.

**All the sense** implies (I think) - complete sense(but not sure...)

Comment: Hi. It's from an expression/idiom.  ["to make all the difference *in the world*"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20all%20the%20difference). It means to be very important, to matter most or very much. However, whoever wrote it has changed  **difference** it to **sense**.  Not sure it really works here, but we'd really need to see the sentence used in context. Where did you find it?

Comment: @BillyKerr https://medium.com/the-shadow/writing-made-simple-according-to-charlie-chaplin-2b9a4b49ff43

Comment: Thanks for the link. In that context, it means something like "then it made complete sense", but whoever wrote it has messed with an existing idiom, and changed its meaning. I'm not sure I really like it TBH.  I'd advise against changing fixed idioms/expressions unless you have a really good reason for doing so.

Comment: "All" belongs to the word class (part of speech) **determinative**. Here "all the sense in the world" is an NP in which the determinative all functions as predeterminer. We can gloss it for comparative purposes as “the entirety of the sense”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Then it made all the sense in the world.*

"All" belongs to the word class (part of speech) determinative.

Grammatically, "all the sense in the world" is an idiomatic NP in which the determinative "all" functions as predeterminer. We can very roughly gloss it for comparative purposes as "the entirety of the sense".